# Single click to edit JTable Cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

I have a JTable with custom editor using JTextPane for html rendering.
Also I want to edit with single click.
It works perfectly if editor component was JTextField.

But I can't edit with single click in case of JTextPane.
Because 'stopCellEditing' is called twice when I select other column.
There is one more strange thing.
When I removed all other component except JTable it works also.

```
//frame.add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

I know `table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);` is releated this problem.
I added this function because I needed it.
I want to know why it only happens when using JTextPane and there is a workaround

Here is a full example:

```
public class Main {
    public Main() {}

    public static class MyCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {
        JTextComponent comp;

        public MyCellEditor (JTextComponent comp) {
            this.comp = comp;
        }

        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                                     boolean isSelected, int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {
            comp.setText((String)value);
            return comp;
        }

        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return comp.getText();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean stopCellEditing() {
            System.err.println("stopCellEditing");
            return super.stopCellEditing();
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
            if (anEvent instanceof MouseEvent) {
                return ((MouseEvent)anEvent).getClickCount() >= 1;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] columnNames = {"Item", "Description"};
        Object[][] data = {
                        {"Item 1", "Description of Item 1"},
                        {"Item 2", "Description of Item 2"},
                        {"Item 3", "Description of Item 3"}};

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(300);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //MyCellEditor myCellEditor = new MyCellEditor(new JTextField());
        MyCellEditor myCellEditor = new MyCellEditor(new JTextPane());
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(myCellEditor);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Also I want .."* Each question thread should focus on a single problem. Speaking of which, what is the question? I suggest *"**How to do** single click editing of a JTable Cell?"*.

Comment: Sorry I want to use JTextPane for JTable editor and it should be possible to edit with single click.

Comment: *"I want.."* What this **needs** is a question. You know, an inquiry ending with a `?` character. Is that so difficult? (<- example of a question) For things you 'want', tell them to the hired help.